# (RoR) How to: link multiple apps, multiple URLs, one database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently developing a site using Ruby on Rails. I am still a beginner who just started around a month ago. I use InstantRails on Windows 7. Here's my question.
Let's say app A is functional using MYSQL database A_development. The files such as views and controller are under folder 'A'. I now know how to, say for example, link www.app.com to this app by opening port 80 and changing some lines in the mySQL config.

In this app, you can register your username, login, and post some messages.

I now want to create some pretty identical apps say B and C. The only thing different will be the posts that shows, and the views. You can still log in with the same username, and everything is saved in the same database.
I now want the URLs to look something like A.app.com leading to app A, B.app.com leading to app B, etc. Can that be achieved? How?

I've been googling for a few days already and I'm still lost.
As I'm new to this forum, I'm not quite sure what info do you guys need. Please list and I'll provide them asap.
Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have 2 (or more) issues...

On the URL front, it probably depends on what your webserver is - is it apache or something else?

In apache you could have multiple URLs point to the same web application or to different ones.

If you there are only going to be 3 or so and not much more, perhaps separate Rails apps for each one will do.

On the database front, if you point each web application at the same database, then that should achieve what you need.  You probably want to a choose a transactional db to ensure updates from one app do not clash with updates from the other - eg if user has their profile window open in both apps and then saves a change to their name - which change is saved...

Given the DB is shared, you probably want to do something to ensure the related views are shared too.  This goes beyond my ruby-fu - perhaps an inhouse plugin/gem would be the best route to go for that...

HTH, chris